# In Access, how to rename query output from checkbox to text of yes/no query?

Tags: ms-access

I have a Access 2010 database with a yes/no field for residing in the city limits or in the surrounding county. I wrote a SQL query to count how many people are in each category. How do I change the row names from Yes/No to "Reside in City" and "Reside in County" in the output table?

```
SELECT Person.ResideCity, Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM Person
GROUP BY Person.ResideCity;

ResideCity    Count
Yes             10
No              23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `IIF` statement. Yes/No fields return -1 for yes and 0 for no. If you need to group by this field, you need the full expression in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT IIF(Person.ResideCity = -1, "Reside In City", "Reside In County") As ResideCity
  , Count(*) AS [Count]
FROM Person
GROUP BY IIF(Person.ResideCity = -1, "Reside In City", "Reside In County");
```

Comment: You can probably just use `IIF(Person.ResideCity ...` instead of `IIF(Person.ResideCity = -1 ...`. Also I would use single quotes instead of double quotes. Double quotes will work in Access queries but if you ever need to use VBA to create SQL and you copy paste that code in a VBA string it will cause problems.

Comment: Two minimalist versions of the above answer:

`SELECT IIF(ResideCity,'Reside In City','Reside In County') As ResideLocation, Count(*) AS [Count] FROM Person GROUP BY IIF(ResideCity,'Reside In City','Reside In County')`
 and 
`SELECT IIF(FIRST(ResideCity),'Reside In City','Reside In County') As ResideLocation, Count(*) AS [Count] FROM Person GROUP BY ResideCity`